# Putting a closure to JS Closures

Tags: javascript

> a closure is the local variables for
>   a function - kept alive after the
>   function has returned.

I'm wrapping my head around JS & jQuery Closures. From the definition above my understanding is a closure allows access to variables outside a function without the
need for creating globals, eliminating the inherent risk. Is my interpretation correct?

As always many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally you would think that when you define a function `foo` the only possible variables that it could read/write are the parameters you pass in to the function when it's called `foo(1, "hello");` and all the `global` variables you defined. This is how C-like languages work.

In **JavaScript** however, you can define a function pretty much *anywhere* and other than global and parameter variables the function can also read/write variables in its parent scopes; for example:

```
var global = "global";
function foo() {
    var one = 1;
    function bar() {
        var two = 2;
        function argh() {
        }
    }
}
```

The function `argh` will be able to read/write variables from all its parent scopes, in this case `two`, `one` and `global` are all accessible to the function `argh`.

I hope this better explains what closures are about - it's not that hard once you under how scoping works in JavaSript. Closures are basically just inner functions that are able to access current and parent scopes... :).

This is quite a powerful concept especially for when you're doing *asynchronous* things. Imagine yourself having to define a function that will run in a different moment in time:

```
// the function we defined below
// will run in 5 seconds in time
setTimeout(function(){

}, 5000);
```

Without the ability of JavaScript functions to access parent scopes we would only be able to access *global* variables. However with JavaScript this is much easier and we can use all available local variables:

```
var foo = "some local variable";
setTimeout(function(){
    alert(foo);
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Technically yes. Realistically no, they are much more complicated and the fact that you have used that grammar to describe them suggests you have a poor understanding of the concept. I would return to the quoted source, after you've visited Robert Harvey's link.

Comment: Also worth reading some of [Douglas Crockford's articles](http://javascript.crockford.com/)

Comment: Thanks both, I'll continue my research.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good example of a use of closures:

```
function makeAddFunction(number1){
    function add(number2){
       return number1 + number2;
    }
    return add;
}

var add2 = makeAddFunction(2);
var add5 = makeAddFunction(5);
console.log(add2(2)); //Will print 4 to the console
console.log(add5(2)); //Will print 7 to the console
console.log(add2(1)); //Will print 3 to the console
```

The best way I have found to understand this concept is to say that when you call the makeAddFunction() and in this case store it in the variable add2 you are taking a snapshot of the outer functions data/state. Then when you call your new function add2() you are accessing that data along with the data passed in to add2() as arguments. The new arguments die after the function has returned but the original snapshot is still there to call again with new arguments.

Answer (score 0):

so far i\I understand is that closure is use for storing data and can access that data everytime when the inner function runs.

and closure pretty much happen due to lexical scope i.e. variable outside of function is avail inside the function.